# possible to stream wma sound files on iPhone/iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming, wma

i searched with keyword "wma" but couldn't find similar posts, so i start this post.

My goal is to download wma files from a known website and playback those files. These wma files are recorded radio programs, a sample link looks like: `mms://media.chinabroadcast.cn/eng/music/morning/2010/0825a.wma`. Online streaming is acceptable by my client.

Now i'm hitting the wall with wma sound file streaming and playback, i'm wondering if it's possible on iPhone/iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to play .wma files on iOS devices?

## No

iPhone (and all Apple iOS devices for that matter) are not capable of playing Windows Media Audio files.  You'll need to transcode or restrict the audio types to mp3 or AAC.